# How many objects is too many for a git repository?

Tags: git, version-control

We are planning to store frequently updated text and graphics in a version control system. It's not source code, but it is mostly text files. No single object is "large", but the size of the repo would grow large with frequent updates.

How can I guess how large in terms of version history is too large to make git practical to use, as opposed to another version control system.

Update: This isn't an answer to the question. But, for my purposes it would probably work to use clone --shallow-since=... based on observing how the repo grows over time, without having an answer to "how many objects".

Comment: Are you going to push them to github/gitlab/whatever? What kinda hardware are we talking about? Images are basically noncompressible and every version will be stored as is for each version.

Comment: git is not the tool for your usecase. every commit would have an extra copy of everything you DIDN'T CHANGE in that commit. 4 commits means the storage size is now 4x the size of the files being version controlled. what you need is a content management system, rather than a version control system. take your content size X number of commits to determine the actual space required. also consider, if you use branches, it could take some time to switch between them. find a system that tracks by file, rather than commit.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Git commits don't work that way. It was built as a content-addresed storage system since day one, before it even was a VCS, so if something did not change there's always only _one_ copy of it. (What causes a repository to grow is files that _do_ change in a way that can't be delta-compressed between revisions, such as many image formats as Gantendo mentioned.)

Comment: For comparison, linux.git has approx. 8,702,895 objects in torvalds/master, but they're _highly_ delta-compressible (i.e. files remain similar between versions) which allows it to remain under 3 GB. Meanwhile chromium.git has around 4,091,578 objects in my outdated copy (less than half of linux.git), yet it's 17 GB. I suspect Microsoft's windows.git would be the largest one, but can't find where its size was publicly mentioned.

Comment: Please review https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F . what you are describing is a delta-based system, which git is explicitly not (or at least thats what they officially tell people).

Comment: @FrankThomas: Git is indeed not delta-based in its overall design, as nearly all of its commands work with "whole" objects (files/blobs, etc), but it still uses delta compression in the lowest storage layer (`.pack` files); see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles. (The difference is that e.g. systems like Hg or SVN _explicitly_ store commits as deltas against older versions of the same file, while Git only does so opportunistically. All Git commands still *think* they work with "whole" objects and are completely oblivious as to how those objects are stored.)

Comment: @FrankThomas: That's still entirely besides the point though, which is that Git is a content-addressed storage system and never stores the same file more than once; even with .pack files and compression out of the question, 4 commits with a file that didn't change will only occupy 1x the space (+ metadata). See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_git_commit_objects and the last diagram in particular, showing that several commits share the same object whenever it has the same contents.

Comment: I don't see a way to reply to anyone.

I should clarify that we need a version control system. I'm considering perforce vs git. I'm aware of how binary data is stored in git. My question is what amount of objects would make a git repo, the repository on the file system, impractical to use given any hardware?

Comment: About the first comment. The repo would only be on disk. Essentially the working copy is used by a program. There would be no pushing to a remote. Branches are needed. This question is not about images, really. I'm trying to predict how many objects with what amount of version history is practical.

Answer (score 0):

#### Considerations ahead of time

Before starting the repository there is one thing you need to decide on:

- Can I rewrite the history?

If you can then you can change the history if you run into performance
problems and thus you don’t need to plan *as much* up front. If you
*can’t* rewrite history then you need to become knowledgable about how
the repository will grow and how Git will deal with it.

#### Repository analysis and Git limitation info

[git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer/) is made by GitHub and can analyze your repository as it
evolves. It also contains documentation about the limitations of Git.

#### One more level of indirection

It seems that the standard way of dealing with largeish files is to add
a level of indirection. You can for example use [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) which
lets you create symlinks to certain files that are deemed “large”.

#### The number of files

I have definitely run into problems when using git-annex because I had a
lot of files. `git-annex` has the `fsck` subcommand, which checks for
file corruption. That command could take hours to complete. It may be
that `git-annex` has a direct solution for that, but what I ended up
doing was taring directories of files that I don’t need to access any
more.